# Error when installing homebrew with ruby

Tags: ruby, osx-lion, homebrew

Trying to install homebrew from here:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected ']'
[This script has been moved.][url]
                             ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Acessing https://raw.github.com/gist/323731 in your browser, you see

> [This script has been moved.][url]
>
> [url]:https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb

But it doesn't seem to work. So use

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

instead.