# Trying to install Homebrew: miscellaneous errors returned

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

My platform is OSX 10.7.5. Ruby version is *ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]*

I am attempting to install Homebrew — to no avail. Here is what I tried so far from the Terminal:

1) Command copied from http://brew.sh/

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

This brings up the message

```
-e:192: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting $end
               .map { |d| File.join(HOMEBREW_PREFIX, d) }
            ^
```

2) From SO
[Error when installing homebrew with ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834804/error-when-installing-homebrew-with-ruby)
I also tried (a)

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

and was returned

```
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
```

and (b)

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb)"
```

resulting in

```
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
```

(a) and (b) both return class 4xx http Client errors.

I would be grateful if anyone could help.

Comment: can you use another version of ruby? rvm install 2.X?

Comment: Thanks, Dan: I am going to give it a go and keep you update.

Comment: Thanks, Dan, this made my day. Please see further down my answer to Ismail M

Comment: BEAUTIFUL. glad that helped :D

Answer (score 1):

Try updating ruby using [rvm](https://rvm.io) to 2.*...

Otherwise, try downloading the script and then running it separately:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install > brew_install.rb
$ ruby brew_install.rb
```

Comment: Please hold on: I am back to work today. I will keep you updated.