# How to install Homebrew without upgrading ruby?

Tags: ruby, homebrew, osx-lion

My setting: Mac OS 10.7.5, ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0].

I've tried installing Homebrew:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I get this message:

```
-e:201: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting $end
           .map { |d| File.join(HOMEBREW_PREFIX, d) }
            ^
```

I read that upgrading ruby may help. When I try to install rvm, this is what I did:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```

I get a message that gpg is not installed. I looked up how to install it, and it happens that I need Homebrew. Instead, I tried:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

It starts to install, but at some point it says

```
About to install Homebrew, press `Enter` for default installation in `/usr/local`,
type new path if you wish custom Homebrew installation (the path needs to be writable for user)
: Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Then I'm back to square one. To install Homebrew, I need a more recent ruby, for which I need rvm, for which I need Homebrew. I don't care about ruby, but if I need it for Homebrew, I'll upgrade it, but I don't see how to get off this circle of dependencies.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214331/trying-to-install-homebrew-miscellaneous-errors-returned/40216592#40216592

Comment: Does that work for you?

Comment: I don't know if there is a solution to your question but personally I would just bite the bullet and upgrade - your ruby version is very old now. Once you have ruby, homebrew and rvm set up there is no reason why you can't create a ruby 1.8.7 environment using rvm if necessary.

Comment: you can install a newer ruby without rvm, rbenv, or homebrew. See https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#building-from-source

Comment: @IsmailM, no, it didn't work. When I try install ruby 2.0, for example, I get the `About to install Homebrew...`, and then that fails again.

Comment: @user36386, I meant did you try to download the homebrew installer to a local file and then install it...

Comment: Try installing homebrew with: `usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/9b97f5fd52ed8fbe00934d0d5886d5631af33716/install)`

Comment: I just tried. I get a `>` prompt, and that's it (whether I type `"` at the end or not). So, that's not working either. UPDATE: @IsmailM Downloading the installer to a local file worked! It took me some time to figure out how to do it, but installation was successful, than you very much.